# Why when I use ".. /" file path to grab an image it doesn't work?

Tags: html

im trying to get an image from "Web DeV"

[html file folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJXxo.png)

[image folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSsY8.png)

the code should be

```html
<img src"../2.jpg">
```

right ?

i tried but it didnt work, tried a different image and still didnt work

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu6hj.png)

[how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJvbb.png)

Comment: im using Vscode btw

Comment: How are you loading the page? By hitting the html or on a local server?

Comment: Also, it might be easier for you to debug if you check whether the full path of image is correct by checking dev tools (inspect element) or by opening the image in new tab.